# Custom dialog box in Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator

I would like to create a service that performs a set of actions based on several parameters
A custom dialog box with multiple radio buttons would be a great way to capture these.
My experience with AppleScript so far only gives me very basic prompts
**How can I use a custom dialog box in Automator?**

Comment: show us your work so far !

Comment: Ben Waldie has a detailed presentation on creating a custom window in Xcode and wiring it up with AppleScript: https://youtu.be/HE5jFCfkD0w?t=320 • more discussion here: https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/using-xcode-cocoa-applescript-asobjc-app-to-provide-rich-gui/410/6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will be of use to you.

[Dialog Toolkit and Dialog Toolkit Plus are ASObjC-based script libraries for showing enhanced dialogs. Add multiple text entry fields, checkboxes, popup menus, radio buttons, path controls, extra buttons and rules to dialogs.](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/Script_Libs.html#DialogToolkit)

Just read the text files included in the bundle to help you get started. Playing around in Script Editor.app, with the sample scripts included, should help you understand the process.

Here are a few examples created with this scripting addition in Script Editor

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `choose from list`.

Like this:

```
on run {input}
    tell application "System Events"
        activate
        set input to (choose from list {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5"} with title "Time to choose" with prompt "Would you rather" & return & "choose from:" OK button name "YEAH " cancel button name "NOT NOW ☠️" default items {"Option 3"}) as text
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Result:

[image]

Then you work the input variable to do different stuff according to the option. 
You can also stack multiple questions and carry on several variables inside the input. In the next argument use `item 1 from input`, `item 2 from input`, etc

Comment: Thanks for suggesting but one list is not enough

Comment: @MonoThreaded you can do as many as you want, one after another

Comment: I tried that but the resulting UX is very clunky

Comment: @MonoThreaded Well I see you got were you wanted. Anyway I'm posting to help other users with minimal goals. Using vannila AS is always better than installing xtra stuff.